# Syntax Error with node_modules in a react native app typescript app ejected from expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I have a react native typescript app that I ejected from expo. I fixed all the errors associated with it and now is able to compile properly. When running on an android emulator. I get a couple of errors. I'm not sure what I'm missing. Does anyone think there's some dependency with expo somewhere?

here is my packages being used in the app:

```
"dependencies": {
"@emotion/native": "^11.0.0",
"@emotion/react": "^11.7.1",
"@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.6",
"@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "4.0.0",
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.0.5",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.1.0",
"@types/jest": "^28.1.4",
"@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
"axios": "^0.24.0",
"dayjs": "^1.10.7",
"expo-location": "~14.0.1",
"lottie-react-native": "5.0.1",
"mobx": "^6.3.12",
"mobx-react-lite": "^3.2.3",
"moment": "^2.29.1",
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-dom": "17.0.2",
"react-hook-form": "^7.22.5",
"react-native": "0.68.2",
"react-native-elements": "^3.4.2",
"react-native-map-clustering": "^3.4.2",
"react-native-maps": "0.29.4",
"react-native-qrcode-svg": "^6.1.2",
"react-native-raw-bottom-sheet": "^2.2.0",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "4.3.1",
"react-native-screens": "~3.10.1",
"react-native-svg": "^12.3.0",
"react-native-web": "0.17.1",
"rn-credit-card": "^0.1.1"
```

},

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

It had to do with react-native-cli.

I removed that node_module and installed it again. and I was able to resolve the issue.

> npm i -g react-native-cli